# Why Can't A Male Mule Have Offspring?

Tags: genetics, hybridization

I've read that female mules can [sometimes](http://www.seattlepi.com/national/article/Mule-does-impossible-Has-a-foal-1250061.php) have offspring, but that male mules are incapable of doing so. Why is that the case? Is their sperm not capable of entering the egg or is their a genetic reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's essentially genetic. The mule is a hybrid of a male donkey and female horse. A donkey has 62 chromosomes, a horse has 64 chromosomes, and a mule has 63 (mix of 62 and 64). There is a mismatch between both number and structure of the chromosomes and as a result, most mules are infertile.

Comment: You say "most mules are infertile". Are you implying that some mules are fertile?

Comment: Yes, there are rare documented cases where mules have birthed foals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule#Fertility

Comment: Bizarre and very interesting!